# How to normalize Keras network output in a regression problem that demands output with unit L2 norm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, regression

My regression problem requires that the network output `y` has unit norm `||y|| = 1.`. I would like to impose that as a `Lambda` layer after the linear activation:

```
from keras import backend as K  
...  
model.add(Dense(numOutputs, activation='linear'))  
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x)))
```

The backend is TensorFlow. The code compiles but the network predicts output vectors with distinct norms (the norm is not 1 and varies).

Any hints regarding what I am doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't passed the `axis` argument to the `K.l2_normalize` function. As a result it would normalize all the elements in the whole batch so that their norm would be equal to one. To resolve this, just pass `axis=-1` to normalize over the last axis:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)))
```